# Android, trying to add a graph

Tags: java, android

I'm using a IOIO board with an Android (nexus simulator) and I have the basic ioio connection going. I can sample 2 analogue pins.

The next step is to try to graph the results.
In dependencies I've got

```
compile 'com.jjoe64:graphview:4.1.0'
```

In MainActivity, onCreate I have (commented out)

```
 graph1 = (GraphView) findViewById(R.id.graph1);
```

In Looper I have (also commented out)

```
 LineGraphSeries<DataPoint> series = new LineGraphSeries<>(new DataPoint[] {
   new DataPoint(0,3), new DataPoint(1,3), new DataPoint(2,6)
});
```

In activity_main.xml I have (commented out)

```
   <com.jjoe64.graphview.GraphView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/graph1"
    android:layout_below="@+id/output1"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"/> -->
```

When I run it I get the message hardware acceleration must be used, but I have in main.AndroidManifest.xml

```
<application
android:allowBackup="true"
android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
android:label="@string/app_name"
android:supportsRtl="true"
android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
```

Since everything is essentially commented out, the program still runs in the basic mode.
As soon as I remove the commenting in activity_main.xml, the program crashes.
I don't know if it is because the hardware acceleration isn't really on, or what else could be wrong?
Any comments would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Having heard no hints, I tried an already compiled graphview application. Finally I had something which worked.

I had a guess that perhaps it might be something in the dependencies. The dependencies are

```
dependencies {
  compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
  testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
  compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.1'
  compile files('libs/GraphView-4.0.1.jar')
//    compile 'com.jjoe64:graphview:4.1.0'
}
```

I added the compile 'com.jjoe64:graphview:4.1.0', which I have in my program. By uncommenting the line and commenting out the line just above it, the program started to fail with the same hardware acceleration must be used message.

Just to be sure I changed the commenting back to the above, did a Clean, and tried again. I was back on line. Why this should make such a difference I have no idea, but for the moment I know how to continue with my project.